# Prevent line breaks in "alert" prompt in javascript

Tags: javascript

I know how to insert line breaks in a JavaScript alert (using '\n'), but how do I prevent them - that is, make the text remain on the same line within the alert.

I have a message I want to display that breaks on the last word of the sentence, leaving a very awkward looking message. So, for example, instead of this:

> Please ensure proper text is entered into the form

The users sees this:

> Please ensure proper text is entered into the
>
> form

...quite unappealing.

I know I could alter the message to possibly make it shorter, but for future reference, I thought I would ask the question.

Comment: What browser are you using? Sounds like a default size `alert` box which is native and can't be changed.

Comment: I doubt you have any control over that.

Comment: I think your results will differ among web browsers. The only way to ensure this works the same across all browsers would be to use a custom alert box (such as the one included with jQueryUI).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I'll implement the solution as a JS/modal implementation as was suggested

Comment: For this project we're using IE - versions 9 through 11.  For some others, we have a cross-browser target

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible, because the styling of the alert dialog that appears depends completely on the browser's implementation. Different screen sizes and different browsers will enforce different maximum / minimum widths on these dialogs. Even shortening your text won't guarantee that it is restricted to one line on all browsers.

Your best solution would be to implement a JavaScript dialog of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript alerts are not customisable in this fashion because they are completely dependent on the browser itself. Consider using an in-DOM modal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make the "alert" window wider, which means text that doesn't fit will wrap to the next line. I would suggest displaying the message in HTML instead.